# Update doesn't work for null values?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data like the following:

```
{   
    title: "whatever"
    answers:[
      {
       "question_id" : 11294,
       "sub_id" : null,
       "_id" : ObjectId("52f90f68bab16dd8595d453e"),
       "values" : [
        "Po&nbsp;"
       ]
      }
    ]
}
```

And I am trying to update it like so:

```
db.participants.update(
    {
        "answers.question_id": 11294,
        "answers.sub_id": null
    },
    {
        $set:
        {
            "answers.$.question": 'test'
        }

    },
    false,
    true
);
```

But it does not work (the record is not updated).  If there is a values for `sub_id` and `answers.sub_id` then the update works fine.  How can I write this update so that it will update records both when they have a value for `answers.sub_id` and when `answers.sub_id` is null?

UPDATE:

I create this index right before I run the query and then delete it after:

```
db.participants.ensureIndex({"answers.question_id": 1, "answers.sub_id": 1});
```

Comment: The query looks correct to me. Also tested it on my machine (mongodb 2.5.4).

Comment: oh weird.. and you definetly tested with null values for `sub_id`?

Comment: Looks like I'm running `2.4.1` I wonder if that would make any difference?

Comment: I tested with the same query (I just included "," after "title: 'whatever'") and it's working fine.

Comment: I couldn't find a bug report / release note for this change. However, the behavior that you expected and that Crasher and me observed is documented, so that's definitely how it *should* behave: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls

Comment: Hrrm ok, maybe I screwed something up.  I'll take a look

Comment: are you sure it is null on mongodb ? if you do db.participants.find().pretty() what do you get?

Comment: Do you have any indices on these fields? And if so, can you add those to the question please.

Comment: @aks, yes, question updated

Comment: @JoséF.Romaniello, yes I'm sure it's `null`.  I have queried the DB manually and confirmed it a few times.

Comment: You should be using elemMatch for any array field comparison as whole. Otherwise you are most likely updating some document value which may not be exactly what you may have meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

```
db.participants.update(
    {
        answers: {$elemMatch: {"question_id": 11294, "sub_id": null}}
    },
    {
        $set:
        {
            "answers.$.question": 'test'
        }

    },
    false,
    true
);
```

The "answers" field is an array, in your example, not a sub-document. Hope this helps.